# Etz Hadas - Alcoholic?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, trees, liquor-beer

I heard that there's a gemara either saying or suggesting that the Etz Hadas was alcoholic in nature. I had a hunch before learning of the Gemara it might have been alcoholic fruit.

So if it's true, what's the actual source?

Comment: if you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one view presented in Sanhedrin 70a:

> אמר רבי זכאי: אמר לו הקדוש ברוך הוא לנח: נח, לא היה לך ללמוד מאדם הראשון, שלא גרם לו אלא יין. כמאן דאמר אותו אילן שאכל ממנו אדם הראשון גפן היה. דתניא, רבי מאיר אומר: אותו אילן שאכל אדם הראשון ממנו גפן היה
>
> The Holy One, blessed be He, said unto Noah: 'Noah, shouldst thou not have taken a warning from Adam, whose transgression was caused by wine?' This agrees with the view that the [forbidden] tree from which Adam ate was a vine. For it has been taught: R. Meir said: That [forbidden] tree from which Adam ate was a vine. (Trans. [here](http://www.come-and-hear.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_70.html))

Comment: And did the vine have time to ferment? This doesn't prove it was alcoholic, just that it was grape-based.

Comment: @DoubleAA I understood that to be the implication of , שלא גרם לו אלא יין